# Stream mov to ipad

Tags: php, iphone, ipad, streaming

Has anyone come across a working implementation of streaming a video from a server (php/linux/apache) to an iPhone or iPad - written in PHP?

Example: http://site.com/file.mov

Direct access plays without issues, but implementing the script here:
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/content-delivery-mobile-devices in appendix A, doesn't improve the situation if your script wraps the the request such as here:

http://site.com/view/file.mov

Where /view/ acts as the script in Appendix A.

I'm seeing the headers being received as indicated in that description, and content being sent of 2bytes in length, but then the iPad returns to the 'broken play button' screen and nothing plays.

Videos used were uploaded from an iPad.

Any links to any working/tested scripts very welcome.

Comment: Vote to close should come with a comment

Comment: I think the only way to get a real stream is using a streaming server. We ran into several problems trying to stream movies through a proxy PHP script. The issue was, that no matter what header we sent, the iOS device always started to download the whole file and this multiple times for one page request, making the counter on the delivering API more or less useless.

Comment: I'm not against using a streaming server to make it work.  What I'm trying to avoid is a public url for a resource so I can determine if the url/resources is accessible to the requester.  What way did you go for streaming and were you able to implement anything in between for authentication?

Comment: Just to add to that, urls I'm using are more like: /u/+$user_resource_key+/

Comment: yes, its easy to do. example script you mentioned has 1 major bug, thats why it doesnt work. Heres how it shud be -   
if( isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']) ) $opts['http']['header']="Range: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'];
$opts['http']['method']= "HEAD"; $conh=stream_context_create($opts);
$opts['http']['method']= "GET"; $cong= stream_context_create($opts);
$out[]= file_get_contents($real_file_location_path_or_url,false,$conh);
$out[]= $http_response_header;
ob_end_clean();
array_map("header",$http_response_header);
readfile($real_file_location_path_or_url,false,$cong);

Comment: i implemented above to create a simple video file streaming proxy in php. user opens up VLC Media Player with above url (for eg - www.example.com/myvideo) and the above script serves the actual / hidden / real file in byte ranges and you can easily play/pause/forward/backward in the file.